# Font is "breaking" from being used in a figure caption (interaction with libertine?)

Tags: fonts, captions, bold, libertine

I am having a strange issue, originally from use of `acmart` but I've been able to make a minimal reproduction with `article`.

Here's my LaTeX source:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{libertine}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\captionsetup{textfont={bf}}

\begin{document}

{\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{b}\selectfont hello}
{\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{b}\selectfont hello}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{
    {\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{b}\selectfont hello}
    {\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{b}\selectfont hello}
  }
\end{figure}

{\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{b}\selectfont hello}
{\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{b}\selectfont hello}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: output]

As you can see, the text in the caption AND after the caption (???) is cmss, but it loses its boldness. Somehow, using cmss-b in the caption breaks future use of cmss-b. This is very strange to me!

I have confirmed that that full preamble is required to reproduce this problem. Removing the import of libertine, the import of caption, or the use of captionsetup restores the behavior I expect. (Naturally, these three lines occur in `acmart` and I can't change them.)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no `b` fontseries for the `cmss` family. Use `bx` instead. On the other hand, I don't know why LaTeX substitutes `bx` in the first two lines, but `n` in the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmss/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmss/m/n' instead on input line 11.
```

and once this happens every time you ask for bold sans serif you get medium weight.

Of course you should *not* use font change commands in the argument to `\caption`, but properly define the style.

If you want to override the class decision about the sans serif font, redefine `\sfdefault`.

But, anyway, if you intend to use `cmss` in a context where `\bfdefault` is `b` instead of `bx`, you can load `t1cmss.fd` and add the missing font substitution.

```
\makeatletter
\input{t1cmss.fd}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmss}{b}{n}{<->ssub*cmss/bx/n}{}
\makeatother
```

You can incorporate it in your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{textfont={bf}}

\makeatletter
\input{t1cmss.fd}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmss}{b}{n}{<->ssub*cmss/bx/n}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

{\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{b}\selectfont hello}
{\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{b}\selectfont hello}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{
    {\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{b}\selectfont hello}
    {\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{b}\selectfont hello}
  }
\end{figure}

{\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{b}\selectfont hello}
{\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{b}\selectfont hello}

\end{document}
```

[image]